# Blender 3.5 cube object doesn't render

Tags: rendering

Original startup file produced problem of not rendering new object but instead restoring a old render of a video.  Went to Animation Workspace and deleted channels and cleaned out the animation workspace and saved to new startup file.  Now Render does not render any object.  I created just a simple cube to work the original problem so the file couldn't be any simpler.

Comment: It sounds as if you need to go to File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings and then File > Save Startup File. You will lose any addons and other settings you've saved but at least you'll start with a clean slate!

Comment: Have you accidentally deleted the default camera? Without a camera in the startup file it will not render anything if you don't add a new one.

Comment: The first answer worked for the simple cube file.  However, when I go back into the current project, there is no change.  I was doing the CGI-Fast Track tutorial Sword In The Stone hoping to learn some new stuff when the problem appears. I went through my backups and they all exhibit the same problem.  I'm going to redo with a clean slate and periodically checked render.